# Print (and store) high ASCII character (╔) in C++ in console

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm making a small program in C++ and I would like to have this character stored in a variable: `╔`. However, I can only do it in a string, and if I use the `'` notation it just shows this: `�`.

Is there anything I can do?

BTW, I use:

- Linux (Mint)
- Visual Studio Code (integrated terminal)

The console shows the characters correctly if I use the `"` notation, so probably it's not a problem with the console itself.

Comment: Non-standard characters are non-standard. That one probably doesn't fit in a single character in the encoding used by your system.

Comment: It's not an ASCII character. It's [U+2554](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2554/index.htm) You probably have it stored as UTF8 and in that case, it's stored as 3 bytes: 0xE2 0x95 0x94

Comment: I looked at the ascii tables and it was shown as an high ascii character (201) so it confused me

Comment: You aren't using an ASCII OS though, Linux is usually UTF-8 so you need to print the 3 bytes Ted mentioned to get the right character

Comment: Ok then I'll find a way to do this with strings instead of chars I guess

Comment: ASCII is only guaranteed up to code 127. The higher codes are a wild west territory of competing standards.

Comment: It's a [DOS Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) to the ASCII table.

Comment: To simply your life, pick a character set, say Unicode, and one of its character encodings, say UTF-8, and use it throughout: console, source code, compiler source character encoding, compiler execution character encoding. (And, be sure to pick a font that supports the characters you use.) Very unlikely that you can pick ASCII itself for all of those. Not even on DOS could you do that.

Comment: @user4581301 ╔ is a character in 32 standard character sets on my system. Do you mean that it's not in C++'s abstract basic execution character set?

Comment: No, I mean the ASCII standard only specifies a 7-bit encoding. Everything else isn't ASCII. Anything added with the last bit is anybody's guess. ╔ could move around. The console might not respect the encoding. It's a cesspit.

Comment: That's one of the old DOS frame border characters. As Thomas Matthews indicated, that is extended-ASCII, most likely code page 437. The displayed code page is a property of the console itself, unrelated to the program. And, it seems that in Win10 you can't set the console to Extended Ascii encodings anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hex notation:

```
  char border = '\xcd';
```

Small program:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
  cout << "border: \xcd\n";

  const char corner = '\xc9';
  cout << "Upper left corner: " << corner << "\n";

  cout << "Paused.  Press ENTER to continue.\n";
  cin.ignore(100000, '\n');

  return 0;
}
```

There are many charts that show an extending ASCII encoding.  Use the hexadecimal value for the character that you need.

Here's a chart from Wikipedia about [DOS extended ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: CP850 is also a "DOS extended ASCII". The term "Extended ASCII" is almost never precise enough to be useful.

Comment: @Volper Do you, your source editor and your compiler agree on which source character encoding you are using? Which is it?

Comment: My editor and console use UTF-8, not sure about the compiler (I use g++), but the custom character works well if it's in a string. I think it's because the `char` type doesn't support more than 1/2 bytes and that is the reason the single quote doesn't work.